# More than 1 eigenvalues = 1 in an linear system $Ax = x$, means?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

I would like to make sure if I made any mistakes.

For a linear system $Ax = x$, if there are more than one eigenvalue of $A$ equal to 1, is that means there is not an unique x solves this linear system?

How should I claim this?

P.S. I forgot to add a restriction that $x$ is an unit vector. I am sorry about this.

Comment: I don't understand "if there are more than one eigenvalue of $A$
equal to 1" - can you clarify please?

Comment: Are you saying if there's an eigenvalue of multiplicity greater than one (i.e that the characteristic polynomial has a repeated root of 1)?

Comment: Perhaps you meant "If the eigenvalue $\;1\;$ has algebraic multiplicity greater than $\;1\;$ ..." ?

Comment: I forgot to add an restriction that $x$ is an unit vector. I am sorry about this.

Comment: @user131605 Funny: you did not address any of the two above comments... -1

Comment: @Nitin Yes, that's what I want to say.

Comment: @user131605 - this is known as the concept of a [Generalized eigenvector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) - read here.

Comment: @Nitin Can you explain what this has to do with generalized eigenvectors? The connection is not obvious to me based on what was written in the question.

Comment: see my previous comment that OP agreed with

Comment: @Nitin I still don't see the connection.

Answer (score 2):

The number $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if the equation $Ax=x$ has a non-zeror solution $x_0$. But for each such solution, $-x_0$ will be another solution and, if $\|x_0\|=1$, then $\|-x_0\|=1$ too.

Therefore, if $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, there will always be at least $2$ solutions.

Comment: I forgot to add an restriction that $x$ is an unit vector. I am sorry about this.

Comment: @user131605 I have edited my answer.

Comment: If A has two eigenvalues equal to 1, then would I have two nonparallel $x_1$, $x_2$ such that both them satisfy $Ax = x$?

Comment: @user131605 Not necessarily.

Comment: Would you might give me an example?

Comment: @user131605 $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$